# Theoretical relativity of black hole and antimatter

Tags: black-holes, antimatter

(Theoretically), can black holes be considered antimatter that just cancels its equivalent mass and goes back to neutral stage? Note: Be kind I am not a physicist
.

Comment: Given that you're not practiced in medicine, we'll go easy on you. Black holes are not anti-matter. When antimatter annihilates regular matter, it loses all mass. Black holes have enormous mass. This means the scenario you propose is not the case of what happens

Answer (score 1):

Black holes are extremely heavy, black bodies, all of which have a singularity in the centre. They are not anti-matter, they are a sort of 'deep well' of space-time, however, their strong gravitational force attracts matter into themselves. When matter and anti-matter annihilate each other, energy is conserved in the form of photons. Ps: A physician has nothing to do with black holes. (Only in extreme cases)

Comment: what can I say .............I messed up

Answer (score 0):

Black holes contain so much energy in so small a space that indeed many particles of tremendous variety can be created and destroyed as long as certain conservation laws aren't being violated.

Although I did crack a smile at the physician comments people made, I would like to let you know that a physicist works with physics and a physician works with medicine.

Comment: what can I say .............I messed up